# Handling escape characters in a string

Tags: python, regex, escaping

There are strings from the user input I need to convert. The use case is pretty simple:

- When a semicolon is in the string, the string is split into multiple lines.
- When there are two semicolons in a row, they're converted to one.

In theory, no big problem.  I use Python, but I'm sure others with other languages will find this as easy with regular expressions.

```
import re

def get_lines(text):
    """Return a list of lines (list of str)."""
    command_stacking = ";"
    delimiter = re.escape(command_stacking)
    re_del = re.compile("(?<!{s}){s}(?!{s})".format(s=delimiter), re.UNICODE)
    chunks = re_del.split(text)

    # Clean the double delimiters
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        chunks[i] = chunk.replace(2 * command_stacking, command_stacking)

    return chunks
```

That seems to work:

```
>>> get_lines("first line;second line;third line with;;a semicolon")
['first line', 'second line', 'third line with;a semicolon']
>>>
```

But when there's three or four semicolons, it doesn't behave as expected.

The multiple semicolons are ignored by the regular expression (as they should), but when replacing `;;` by `;`, `;;;` is replaced by `;;`, `;;;;` is replaced by `;;...` and so on.  It would be great if 2 was replaced by 1, 3 by 2, 4 by 3... that's something I could explain to my users.

What would be the best solution to do that?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repl argument of re.sub can be a function.

```
>>> s = 'a;;b;;;c;;;;d'
>>> pattern = ';{2,}'
>>> def f(m):
    return m.group(0)[1:]

>>> re.sub(pattern, f, s)
'a;b;;c;;;d'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the string `replace` method use `re.sub()` with `count=1`

```
import re
re.sub(';;', ';', 'foo;;;bar', count=1)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: looks like the best solution, even if I'm not sure to see how it works.  It seems to replace two semicolons by one, three by two, four by three, five by four and so on.

Comment: The `count=1` argument tells it to only replace one instance of the double semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) with look arounds.

**Example**

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<!;);(?!;)', string)
['first line', 'second line', 'third line with;;a semicolon']
```

**Regex**

- `(?<!;)` Negative look behind. Checks if the `;` is not preceded by another `;`

  - `;` Matches the `;`
- `(?!;)` Negative look ahead. Checks if the `;` is not followed by another `;`

---

```
>>> [x.replace(';;', ';') for x in re.split(r'(?<!;);(?!;)', string)]
['first line', 'second line', 'third line with;a semicolon']
```